# Mysql fetch all rows and echo as json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've got a database with 5 columns and multiple rows. I want to fetch the first 3 rows and echo them as an array. So far I can only get the first row (I'm new to PHP and mysql). Here's my PHP so far:

```
//==== FETCH DATA
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName");
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);    

//==== ECHO AS JSON
echo json_encode($array);
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't use `mysql_` functions, use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

Comment: Also note that mysql supports the datatype JSON since mysql 5.7.8

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to loop through the results.  `mysql_fetch_row` gets them one at a time.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

The code would end up like:

```
$jsonData = array();
while ($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $jsonData[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($jsonData);
//json_encode()
```

**PLEASE NOTE**
The mysql extension is deprecated in PHP 5.5, as stated in the comments you should use mysqli or PDO.  You would just substitute `mysqli_fetch_row` in the code above.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Answer (score 3):

I do like this while quering an ODBC database connection with PHP 5.5.7, the results will be in JSON format:

```
$conn = odbc_connect($odbc_name, 'user', 'pass');
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sql_query);
```

Fetching results allowing edit on fields:

```
while( $row = odbc_fetch_array($result) ) { 
     $json['field_1'] = $row['field_1'];
     $json['field_2'] = $row['field_2'];
     $json['field_3'] = $row['field_1'] + $row['field_2'];

     array_push($response, $json); 
  }
```

Or if i do not want to change anything i could simplify like this:

```
while ($array = odbc_fetch_array($result)) { $response[] = $array; }
```

What if i want to return the results in JSON format?, easy:

```
echo json_encode($response, true);
```

You can change odbc_fetch_array for mysqli_fetch_array to query a MySql db.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) `mysql_fetch_row` (besides that it's deprecated and you should use mysqli or PDO)

> Returns a numerical array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

so you need for example a while loop to fetch all rows:

```
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

I leave it to you how to only fetch 3 rows :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this in some kind of a loop, mysql_fetch_row returns results one at a time.

See example:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php#example-1794

Answer (score -1):

$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM $tableName ORDER BY id  LIMIT 3");

$json = array();
while($array = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

$json[] = $array;
}

echo json_encode($json);

Comment: try to explain your answer instead of using code only