# Get images in mysql table to appear in javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have some images in the table `images`, the fields are `id`, `name` and `photo`. Where the image exists in `photo`.

At the minute, the code below not getting any images, although there should be about 4 images that match the query. The images that meet the query should go  into the `slideshowimages("")` variable.

```
<?php
// Connect to the database
   require('mysqli.php');

// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$directory = '';
while( $image = $result->fetch_assoc() )
$directory .= ($directory != '' ? "," : '') . ('"/images/'.$image["photo"] .    '"');


// Check if it was successfull
if($image) {

// if there are images for this page, run the javascript
?><script>


//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links

        //NEED TO GET ALL RELEVANT IMAGE LOCATIONS INTO LINE BELOW
slideshowimages("<?php echo $directory ?>")

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=2000

var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
whichlink=whichimage
if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
whichimage++
else
whichimage=0
setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()


</script> <?php
} else {
    // If there are not any images for this page, leave the space blank
    echo "";
    }

// Close the mysql connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

The JavaScript that is in the `head`

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1">

var slideimages=new Array()
var slidelinks=new Array()
function slideshowimages(){
for (i=0;i<slideshowimages.arguments.length;i++){
slideimages[i]=new Image()
slideimages[i].src=slideshowimages.arguments[i]
}
}

</script>
```

[image: Screenshot of source code, when code is commented out]

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php   `Fetch a result row as an associative array`. One **SINGLE** row...

Comment: how would i write that into the code?

Comment: You need to loop through the results: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511367/mysql-fetch-all-rows-and-echo-as-json

Comment: please could you provide some code? im really struggling with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nice and simply way, is to use an [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) call, to get your image urls in a [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) array, which you can parse to a javascript array, and iterate and so on. In that case, the added bonus is that you can separate your code to different files by language, and it makes a way nicer code.

But in your current code, you have to iterate your mysqli results with a simple loop. For example:

```
//...
// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$directory = '';
while( $image = $result->fetch_assoc() )
    $directory .= ($directory != '' ? ',' : '') . ("'/images/".$image['photo'] . "'");
//...
```

In this case, your `$directory` variable be like something like this:

```
'/images/image1.jpg','/images/image2.jpg','/images/image3.jpg'
```

And you hopefully can pass it to the javascript function as an argument list.

I hope I could help.

Comment: First of all, thanks! - I have copied your edit into my code. However, it is not displaying any images. How do i pass the code to the as an argument list?

Comment: i have got the `slideshowimages("")` displaying the variable correctly! however this is only when the javascript is commented out. Why doesnt it work when i uncomment? - i have updated my code in the question.

Comment: Which part of the js code is commented out? When it's not, what is the js error or warning you're getting?

Comment: im not getting any error or warning. Its just not showing any images. When i comment out anything after `if($image)` to just before  `$conn->close();` i can see in the source code that the `slideshowimages` is filling the `()` with the file locations. When i uncomment it, as i say, no images appear on the screen

Comment: Source code is in the question. It looks like the php is going straight to the `else` and bypassing the javascript. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's because the `$image` variable does not exists any more in the scope of the `if($image)`. If a variable is defined in a scope (usually defined by `{}` brackets, which I left out in the case of the while loop, cause there's only one line in the scope), it's going to become a so called local variable, meaning it's only exists it the context of said scope.
In your case it means, that you have to check `if($directory != '')` instead of `if($image)`, to check if you have any value for your js function.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. Silly mistake not replacing the variable really - sorry.

Comment: I'm glad i could help. :)